# Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000014 (code=1), thread 15566

Tags: android, fatal-error, crash-reports

I am trying to add buddy in CSipSimple by the following code .

```
public int addBuddy(String buddyUri) throws SameThreadException {
        created = true ;
        if (!created) {
            return -1;
        }
        int[] p_buddy_id = new int[1];
        pjsua.start();

        pjsua_buddy_config buddy_cfg = new pjsua_buddy_config();
        pjsua.buddy_config_default(buddy_cfg);
        buddy_cfg.setSubscribe(1);
        buddy_cfg.setUri(pjsua.pj_str_copy(buddyUri));
        pjsua.buddy_add(buddy_cfg, p_buddy_id);
        System.out.println("Buddy Id is  "+p_buddy_id[0]);
        return p_buddy_id[0];
    }
```

When the app enters into the following line

```
    pjsua.buddy_add(buddy_cfg, p_buddy_id);
```

I am getting the following error and the app crashes .

```
03-27 12:12:42.007  15566-15566/com.csipsimple A/libc﹕ Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000014 (code=1), thread 15566 (com.csipsimple)
```

How can I solve this error ? Any advice is of great help .

Comment: This is an error related to any memory fault. You might not have freed the memory properly  which you acquired before. If you're running threads, please check if they are closed or cancelled properly.

Comment: I am not running threads . I am not also allocating memory .

Comment: What's `pjsua` then?